# How to get historical Firebase Crashlytics and Events data in BigQuery?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Need some help with accessing historical data for Firebase Crashlytics and Events data in BigQuery.

We have linked BigQuery to firebase and we are able to get only last 2 months of data in BigQuery at this moment.

Can you please suggest a way to get the data since the inception of the app?

Comment: When did you link your Firebase to BigQuery? The last two months of data are related to which data? Crashlytics, Events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Firebase` doesn't keep the events data indefinitely which makes this feature not feasible at the moment. 
Currently, your data will start being exported since the moment you enable the `BigQuery` connection, i.e. you can't access your historical data.

If you think this feature would be useful for you and for other people, I encourage you to request it in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features).

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We recently linked to BigQuery and the app has been running since early 2019. Looks like we will be losing a of data :(

Comment: I guess that some kind of analysis will need historical data. In this case, the only option at the moment is to wait for new data to be created :/

Comment: If this answer helped you somehow, consider upvoting :)